# React: Variable after keyname in map function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

Hi I have this Code with objects:

```
const data = [{
item1: {
    ans1: "Ich",
    ans2: "Du",
    ans3: "Jemand",
    ans4: "Egal",
    correct: 3,
    quest: "Wer hat die Kokosnuss geklaut?"
}];
```

and this:

```
    render() {
    const hereGoesMyLevelNum = this.state.level;
    const answers = data.map((answer) => {
        return (
          <ul>
              <li>{answer.item1.ans1}</li>
              <li>{answer.item1.ans2}</li>
              <li>{answer.item1.ans3}</li>
              <li>{answer.item1.ans4}</li>
          </ul>
        )
    });

    return (
      <div className="App">
         <ul>{answers}</ul>
      </div>
    );}} export default App;
```

I want to get the "answers.items" dynamically by passing the level number from the state to it.
Something like:

```
{answer.item{hereGoesMyLevelNum}.ans1}
```

Can you help me please? :)

Answer (score 3):

Use square brackets like this

```
{answer["item"+hereGoesMyLevelNum].ans1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Es6 Computed property keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) syntax (with combination of [ES6 Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)).

**Computed property keys**

```
const id = 1;
const myKeyName = 'key' + id;
myObject[myKeyName]
```

**Combined with Template literals**

```
const id = 1;
const myKeyName = `key${id}`;
myObject[myKeyName]
```

**Running Example:**

```js
const data = [
  {
    item1: {
      ans1: "Ich",
      ans2: "Du",
      ans3: "Jemand",
      ans4: "Egal",
      correct: 3,
      quest: "Wer hat die Kokosnuss geklaut?"
    }
  }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      level: 1
    };
  }


  render() {
    const hereGoesMyLevelNum = this.state.level;
    return (
      <div>
        {
          data.map((answer) => {
            const lvlAnswer = `item${hereGoesMyLevelNum}`;
          return (
            <ul>
              <li>{answer[lvlAnswer].ans1}</li>
              <li>{answer[lvlAnswer].ans2}</li>
              <li>{answer[lvlAnswer].ans3}</li>
              <li>{answer[lvlAnswer].ans4}</li>
            </ul>
          )
        })
       }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to dynamically get property names from your object.

**Example**

```
// array like object
var obj = { 0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c' };
console.log(Object.keys(obj)); // console: ['0', '1', '2']
```

If you only have one property in your object you can do something like below.

```
const answers = data.map((answer) = > {

  // Gets the first property name
  const itemLevel = Object.keys(answer)[0];

  // Loops through the inner properties and returns list items
  const listItems = Object.keys(answer[itemLevel]).map((d) => {
    if (d.startsWith('ans')) return (<li>{answer[itemLevel][d]}</li>);
  });

  return (<ul>{listItems}</ul>);
});
```